# how to make a screen in android that runs only when the app installs

Tags: android, installation

I am making an Android project. In that project i want a screen to appear only during the app installation and not every time we start the app. For eg. in whatsapp the page in which we put our name appears only during installation. I want exactly that type of a screen. I am fairly new to android programming so any help will be appreciated. Thanks! Cheers!

Comment: Use shared preference and make the boolean true once the activity you one to start only once is launched for the first time. Then from your launcher activity keep checking that boolean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to identify if it is the "First time" the app is launched.
Just use a **Boolean variable** ("app_first_time") and change its value to ***false*** after your task runs for the first time.

```
final String PREFS_NAME = "PrefsFile";

SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

if (settings.getBoolean("app_first_time", true)) {
    //here the app is being launched for first time, launch your screen     
    settings.edit().putBoolean("app_first_time", false).commit(); 
}
```